# If the $n^{th}$ partial sum of a series $\sum a_n$ is $S_n = \frac{n-1}{n+1}$, find $a_n$ and the sum.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If the $n^{th}$ partial sum of a series $\sum a_n$ is $S_n = \dfrac{n-1}{n+1}$, find $a_n$ and the sum.

By definition,  the sum of the series is the $\lim n\to\infty$ of it's $n^{th}$ partial sum.

$$\text{ Sum = } \lim_{n\to\infty} = \dfrac{n-1}{n+1} = 1$$

I am asked to find $a_n$. How do I do this? What is the procedure?

Comment: Hint:$$S_n-S_{n-1}=~?$$(by the definition of a partial sum of course)

Comment: I believe it is $a_n$! :o

Comment: :-) Well there you go!

Comment: Really nice hint thanks!

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt There is the issue of a seed value, else the difference equation is not fully specified.  ;-))

Comment: In the future, please avoid using `\dfrac` in titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_n$ be the partial sum of a sequence $a_n$.  Then, we can write

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k \tag1$$

for $n\ge 1$.

Next, using the hint in the comment from S.B. Art, we have from $(1)$

$$a_n = S_{n}-S_{n-1}=\frac{2}{n}-\frac2{n+1} \tag2$$

for $n\ge 2$.  The expression in $(2)$ is not valid for $n=1$ since $S_0$ is not defined by $(1)$.

However, we are given $S_n=\frac{n-1}{n+1}$.  Thus, $S_1=0$ and hence $a_1=0$ also.

Finally, we can write

> $$a_k=\begin{cases}\frac2k-\frac2{k+1}&,k\ge 2\\\\0&,k=1\end{cases}$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got the $k = 1 \to 0$ part... using the $a_n$ that we found, why can't we just sub in $n=1$, which yields $$\dfrac{2}{1} - \dfrac{2}{1+1} = 2-1 =1$$
Why do you have it as **another** case?

Comment: Is it because we use $S_{n} - S_{n-1}$, but we get $S_{1} - S_{0}$, and $S_{0}$ is not defined. Is that the reasoning?

Comment: @KSplitX Yes, that is precisely the reason.  Note that if we simply use $a_k=\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}$ for all $k\ge 1$, then $S_n=2-\frac{2}{n+1}$.